# Skip button - how to stop a function with another function

Tags: javascript, function

I have two functions. The first function is using typed.js to write some text in a div (.con). Then I have a skip button and another function, that should stop the typing and just display the text.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="skip()">skip</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function typing() {
    $(.con).typed({
        strings: ["text"],
        stringsElement: null,
        typeSpeed: 30,
        startDelay: 400,
        showCursor: false,
        cursorChar: "|",
        attr: null,
        contentType: 'html',
      });
}

function skip() {
    $(".con").html("TEXT");
}
```

The problem is that even though it displays the text, it then disappears as typed.js is still writing the text. I don't know to stop the previous function with this function.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your typing function?

Comment: This is all I have in the typing function - just the "text" is way longer

Comment: Do you notice any difference in `$(.con)` and `$(".con")` ? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to call on the typing stop method like this to prevent it continuing to put in the text and allow you to set it:

```
function typing() {
    window.conTyped = $(".con").typed({
        strings: ["text"],
        stringsElement: null,
        typeSpeed: 30,
        startDelay: 400,
        showCursor: false,
        cursorChar: "|",
        attr: null,
        contentType: 'html',
      });
}

function skip() {
    window.conTyped.stop();
    $(".con").html("TEXT");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for stop, pause and clear text is given below.**
typed.js is attached below please leave it do not  consider it and confuse your self.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var typed = Typed.new("#typed", {
    stringsElement: document.getElementById('typed-strings'),
    typeSpeed: 30,
    backDelay: 500,
    loop: false,
    contentType: 'html', // or text
    // defaults to null for infinite loop
    loopCount: null,
    callback: function() {
      foo();
    },
    resetCallback: function() {
      newTyped();
    }
  });

  var resetElement = document.querySelector('.reset');
  if (resetElement) {
    resetElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.getElementById('typed')._typed.reset();
    });
  }

  document.getElementById("stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
    typed[0].stop(false);
  });

  document.getElementById("stop-reset").addEventListener("click", function() {
    typed[0].stop(true);
  });

  document.getElementById("start").addEventListener("click", function() {
    typed[0].start();
  });
});

function newTyped() { /* A new typed object */ }

function foo() {
  console.log("Callback");
}
















//below code consists of typed.js dont confuse with it
//Please take it as a note


// The MIT License (MIT)

// Typed.js | Copyright (c) 2016 Matt Boldt | www.mattboldt.com

// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.




! function(window, document, $) {

 "use strict";

 var Typed = function(el, options) {
  var self = this;

  // chosen element to manipulate text
  this.el = el;

  // options
  this.options = {};
  Object.keys(defaults).forEach(function(key) {
   self.options[key] = defaults[key];
  });
  Object.keys(options).forEach(function(key) {
   self.options[key] = options[key];
  });

  // attribute to type into
  this.isInput = this.el.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'input';
  this.attr = this.options.attr;

  // show cursor
  this.showCursor = this.isInput ? false : this.options.showCursor;

  // text content of element
  this.elContent = this.attr ? this.el.getAttribute(this.attr) : this.el.textContent;

  // html or plain text
  this.contentType = this.options.contentType;

  // typing speed
  this.typeSpeed = this.options.typeSpeed;

  // add a delay before typing starts
  this.startDelay = this.options.startDelay;

  // backspacing speed
  this.backSpeed = this.options.backSpeed;

  // amount of time to wait before backspacing
  this.backDelay = this.options.backDelay;

  // Fade out instead of backspace
  this.fadeOut = this.options.fadeOut;
  this.fadeOutClass = this.options.fadeOutClass;
  this.fadeOutDelay = this.options.fadeOutDelay;

  // div containing strings
  if($ && this.options.stringsElement instanceof $) {
   this.stringsElement = this.options.stringsElement[0]
  } else {
   this.stringsElement = this.options.stringsElement;
  }

  // input strings of text
  this.strings = this.options.strings;

  // character number position of current string
  this.strPos = 0;

  // current array position
  this.arrayPos = 0;

  // number to stop backspacing on.
  // default 0, can change depending on how many chars
  // you want to remove at the time
  this.stopNum = 0;

  // Looping logic
  this.loop = this.options.loop;
  this.loopCount = this.options.loopCount;
  this.curLoop = 0;

  // for stopping
  this.pause = {
   status: false
  };

  // custom cursor
  this.cursorChar = this.options.cursorChar;

  // shuffle the strings
  this.shuffle = this.options.shuffle;
  // the order of strings
  this.sequence = [];

  // All systems go!
  this.build();
 };

 Typed.prototype = {

  constructor: Typed,

  init: function() {
   // begin the loop w/ first current string (global self.strings)
   // current string will be passed as an argument each time after this
   var self = this;
   self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    for (var i=0;i<self.strings.length;++i) self.sequence[i]=i;

    // shuffle the array if true
    if(self.shuffle) self.sequence = self.shuffleArray(self.sequence);

    // Start typing
    self.typewrite(self.strings[self.sequence[self.arrayPos]], self.strPos);
   }, self.startDelay);
  },

  build: function() {
   var self = this;
   // Insert cursor
   if (this.showCursor === true) {
    this.cursor = document.createElement('span');
    this.cursor.className = 'typed-cursor';
    this.cursor.innerHTML = this.cursorChar;
    this.el.parentNode && this.el.parentNode.insertBefore(this.cursor, this.el.nextSibling);
   }
   if (this.stringsElement) {
    this.strings = [];
    this.stringsElement.style.display = 'none';
    var strings = Array.prototype.slice.apply(this.stringsElement.children);
    strings.forEach(function(stringElement){
     self.strings.push(stringElement.innerHTML);
    });
   }
   this.init();
  },

  // pass current string state to each function, types 1 char per call
  typewrite: function(curString, curStrPos) {

   if (this.fadeOut && this.el.classList.contains(this.fadeOutClass)) {
    this.el.classList.remove(this.fadeOutClass);
    this.cursor.classList.remove(this.fadeOutClass);
   }

   // varying values for setTimeout during typing
   // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
   var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + this.typeSpeed;
   var self = this;
   
   // exit when stopped
   if (self.pause.status === true) {

    //remove text from DOM if true
    if(self.pause.removeText) {
     self.el.innerHTML = "";
    }

    //set properties for start function
    self.pause.typewrite = true;
    self.pause.curString = curString;
    self.pause.curStrPos = curStrPos;

    return;
   }

   // ------------- optional ------------- //
   // backpaces a certain string faster
   // ------------------------------------ //
   // if (self.arrayPos == 1){
   //  self.backDelay = 50;
   // }
   // else{ self.backDelay = 500; }

   // contain typing function in a timeout humanize'd delay
   self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // check for an escape character before a pause value
    // format: \^\d+ .. eg: ^1000 .. should be able to print the ^ too using ^^
    // single ^ are removed from string
    var charPause = 0;
    var substr = curString.substr(curStrPos);
    if (substr.charAt(0) === '^') {
     var skip = 1; // skip atleast 1
     if (/^\^\d+/.test(substr)) {
      substr = /\d+/.exec(substr)[0];
      skip += substr.length;
      charPause = parseInt(substr);
     }

     // strip out the escape character and pause value so they're not printed
     curString = curString.substring(0, curStrPos) + curString.substring(curStrPos + skip);
    }

    if (self.contentType === 'html') {
     // skip over html tags while typing
     var curChar = curString.substr(curStrPos).charAt(0);
     if (curChar === '<' || curChar === '&') {
      var tag = '';
      var endTag = '';
      if (curChar === '<') {
       endTag = '>'
      }
      else {
       endTag = ';'
      }
      while (curString.substr(curStrPos + 1).charAt(0) !== endTag) {
       tag += curString.substr(curStrPos).charAt(0);
       curStrPos++;
       if (curStrPos + 1 > curString.length) { break; }
      }
      curStrPos++;
      tag += endTag;
     }
    }

    // timeout for any pause after a character
    self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
     if (curStrPos === curString.length) {
      // fires callback function
      self.options.onStringTyped(self.arrayPos);

      // is this the final string
      if (self.arrayPos === self.strings.length - 1) {
       // animation that occurs on the last typed string
       self.options.callback();

       self.curLoop++;

       // quit if we wont loop back
       if (self.loop === false || self.curLoop === self.loopCount)
        return;
      }

      self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
      }, self.backDelay);

     } else {

      /* call before functions if applicable */
      if (curStrPos === 0) {
       self.options.preStringTyped(self.arrayPos);
      }

      // start typing each new char into existing string
      // curString: arg, self.el.html: original text inside element
      var nextString = curString.substr(0, curStrPos + 1);
      if (self.attr) {
       self.el.setAttribute(self.attr, nextString);
      } else {
       if (self.isInput) {
        self.el.value = nextString;
       } else if (self.contentType === 'html') {
        self.el.innerHTML = nextString;
       } else {
        self.el.textContent = nextString;
       }
      }

      // add characters one by one
      curStrPos++;
      
      self.typewrite(curString, curStrPos);
     }
     // end of character pause
    }, charPause);
    // humanized value for typing
   }, humanize);

  },

  backspace: function(curString, curStrPos) {
   var self = this;

   if (self.pause.status === true) {

    //remove text from DOM if true
    if(self.pause.removeText) {
     self.el.innerHTML = "";
    }

    //set properties for start function
    self.pause.typewrite = false;
    self.pause.curString = curString;
    self.pause.curStrPos = curStrPos;

    return;
   }
   
   if (this.fadeOut){
    this.initFadeOut();
    return;
   }

   // varying values for setTimeout during typing
   // can't be global since number changes each time loop is executed
   var humanize = Math.round(Math.random() * (100 - 30)) + this.backSpeed;

   self.timeout = setTimeout(function() {

    // ----- this part is optional ----- //
    // check string array position
    // on the first string, only delete one word
    // the stopNum actually represents the amount of chars to
    // keep in the current string. In my case it's 14.
    // if (self.arrayPos == 1){
    //  self.stopNum = 14;
    // }
    //every other time, delete the whole typed string
    // else{
    //  self.stopNum = 0;
    // }

    if (self.contentType === 'html') {
     // skip over html tags while backspacing
     if (curString.substr(curStrPos).charAt(0) === '>') {
      var tag = '';
      while (curString.substr(curStrPos - 1).charAt(0) !== '<') {
       tag -= curString.substr(curStrPos).charAt(0);
       curStrPos--;
       if (curStrPos < 0) { break; }
      }
      curStrPos--;
      tag += '<';
     }
    }

    // ----- continue important stuff ----- //
    // replace text with base text + typed characters
    var nextString = curString.substr(0, curStrPos);
    self.replaceText(nextString);

    // if the number (id of character in current string) is
    // less than the stop number, keep going
    if (curStrPos > self.stopNum) {
     // subtract characters one by one
     curStrPos--;
     // loop the function
     self.backspace(curString, curStrPos);
    }
    // if the stop number has been reached, increase
    // array position to next string
    else if (curStrPos <= self.stopNum) {
     self.arrayPos++;

     if (self.arrayPos === self.strings.length) {
      self.arrayPos = 0;

      // Shuffle sequence again
      if(self.shuffle) self.sequence = self.shuffleArray(self.sequence);

      self.init();
     } else
      self.typewrite(self.strings[self.sequence[self.arrayPos]], curStrPos);
    }

    // humanized value for typing
   }, humanize);

  },

  // Adds a CSS class to fade out current string
  initFadeOut: function(){
   self = this;
   this.el.className += ' ' + this.fadeOutClass;
   this.cursor.className += ' ' + this.fadeOutClass;
   return setTimeout(function() {
    self.arrayPos++;
    self.replaceText('')
    self.typewrite(self.strings[self.sequence[self.arrayPos]], 0);
   }, self.fadeOutDelay);
  },

  // Replaces current text in the HTML element
  replaceText: function(str) {
   if (this.attr) {
    this.el.setAttribute(this.attr, str);
   } else {
    if (this.isInput) {
     this.el.value = str;
    } else if (this.contentType === 'html') {
     this.el.innerHTML = str;
    } else {
     this.el.textContent = str;
    }
   }
  },

  // Shuffles the numbers in the given array.
  shuffleArray: function(array) {
   var tmp, current, top = array.length;
   if(top) while(--top) {
    current = Math.floor(Math.random() * (top + 1));
    tmp = array[current];
    array[current] = array[top];
    array[top] = tmp;
   }
   return array;
  },

  // Start & Stop currently not working

  // , stop: function() {
  //     var self = this;

  //     self.stop = true;
  //     clearInterval(self.timeout);
  // }

  // , start: function() {
  //     var self = this;
  //     if(self.stop === false)
  //        return;

  //     this.stop = false;
  //     this.init();
  // }

  // Reset and rebuild the element
  reset: function() {
   var self = this;
   clearInterval(self.timeout);
   var id = this.el.getAttribute('id');
   this.el.textContent = '';
   if (typeof this.cursor !== 'undefined' && typeof this.cursor.parentNode !== 'undefined') {
    this.cursor.parentNode.removeChild(this.cursor);
   }
   this.strPos = 0;
   this.arrayPos = 0;
   this.curLoop = 0;
   // Send the callback
   this.options.resetCallback();
  },

  stop: function(removeText) {
   if(!this.pause.status) {
    this.pause = {
     status: true, 
     removeText: removeText
    };
   };
  },

  start: function() {
   if(this.pause.status) {
    this.pause.status = false;
    this.pause.removeText = false;

    if(this.pause.typewrite) {
     this.typewrite(this.pause.curString, this.pause.curStrPos);
    } else {
     this.backspace(this.pause.curString, this.pause.curStrPos);
    };
   };
  }
 };

 Typed.new = function(selector, option) {
  var instances = [];
  var elements = Array.prototype.slice.apply(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  elements.forEach(function(element) {
   var instance = element._typed,
       options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
   if (instance) { instance.reset(); }
   element._typed = instance = new Typed(element, options);
   if (typeof option == 'string') instance[option]();

   //add new instance to instances array
   instances.push(instance);
  });

  return instances;
 };

 if ($) {
  $.fn.typed = function(option) {
   return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        data = $this.data('typed'),
        options = typeof option == 'object' && option;
    if (data) { data.reset(); }
    $this.data('typed', (data = new Typed(this, options)));
    if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]();
   });
  };
 }

 window.Typed = Typed;

 var defaults = {
  strings: ["These are the default values...", "You know what you should do?", "Use your own!", "Have a great day!"],
  stringsElement: null,
  // typing speed
  typeSpeed: 0,
  // time before typing starts
  startDelay: 0,
  // backspacing speed
  backSpeed: 0,
  // shuffle the strings
  shuffle: false,
  // time before backspacing
  backDelay: 500,
  // Fade out instead of backspace
  fadeOut: false,
  fadeOutClass: 'typed-fade-out',
  fadeOutDelay: 500, // milliseconds
  // loop
  loop: false,
  // false = infinite
  loopCount: false,
  // show cursor
  showCursor: true,
  // character for cursor
  cursorChar: "|",
  // attribute to type (null == text)
  attr: null,
  // either html or text
  contentType: 'html',
  // call when done callback function
  callback: function() {},
  // starting callback function before each string
  preStringTyped: function() {},
  //callback for every typed string
  onStringTyped: function() {},
  // callback for reset
  resetCallback: function() {}
 };


}(window, document, window.jQuery);
```

```css
typed-cursor {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 100;
  -webkit-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  -ms-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  -o-animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
  animation: blink 0.7s infinite;
}

@-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.typed-fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  animation: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s;
}

.button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500);
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

a:hover {
  color: #999;
}

p {
  line-height: 2em;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrap {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 150px auto;
}

.type-wrap {
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: #CCC 1px solid;
}

.links {
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 0.75em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1 class="h1">Typed.js</h1>

  <div class="type-wrap">
    <div id="typed-strings">
      <span>Typed.js is a <strong>JavaScript</strong> library.</span>
      <p>It <em>types</em> out sentences.</p>
      <p>And then deletes them.</p>
      <p>Try it out!</p>
    </div>
    <span id="typed" style="white-space:pre;"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <a href="http://www.mattboldt.com/demos/typed-js">View original demo</a> | <a href="http://www.mattboldt.com">View mattboldt.com</a> | <a href="http://www.twitter.com/atmattb">Complain to Matt about how awful this is</a>
  </div>
  <button id="stop" class="button">Stop typing</button>
  <button id="stop-reset" class="button">Stop typing and clear text</button>
  <button id="start" class="button">Start typing</button>
</div>
```